# Ajax-submit form on "check box onclick ": why this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, onclick, submit

I need to have a checkbox which ajax-submits a form.

The following code throws an error "index 112009 out of string". What's
wrong here?

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => { whatever_url } do -%>

<%= check_box_tag 'whatever', nil, whatever, { :onclick => "#{remote_function('this.form.submit();')}" } %>

<% end -%>
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Tom

Comment: what is method remote_function ?

Comment: it's this one: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001653

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are abusing the `remote_function` helper. Its purpose is to generate the same javascript as is generated with `link_to_remote` et al., like, to update a div with the result of an AJAX call. In your case you need a simple thing like

```
<%= check_box_tag 'whatever', nil, whatever, { :onclick => "$('your_form').onsubmit();" } %>
```

Note the `onsubmit`, not `submit`. This is because the code you need to submit the form via AJAX is present in the `onsubmit` attribute of the form.