# Form is not submitted properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a Rails app that shows restaurant recommendations near the user.

There is a `Posts#index` page, which shows all the `Restaurant`s, and each `Restaurant` has different params. The one I'm most interested in is `Zagat_status`.

When user clicks check box for `Zagat_status`, I want to update the `Posts#index` view so that it only shows `Restaurant`s where params `zagat_status = "Yes"`.

My files are below.  I suspect the problem is in my Index file.  What am I missing/how do I get this to work?

**views/posts/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="map-side-bar">
    <div class="search-filter">
      <form>
        <span>Accolades</span>
        <div class="accolades-panel">

          <label>
            Zagat<dd>rated</dd><input type="checkbox" name="zagat_status" value="Yes">
          </label>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :zagat_status, -> (zagat_status) { where zagat_status: zagat_status }

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :address, presence: true

  def self.search(query)
    where("name like ? OR city like ? OR address like ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
  end
end
```

**controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    if params[:search]
      @posts = @posts.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    end
    if params[:zagat_status].present?
      @posts = @posts.zagat_status(params[:zagat_status]).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
```

Comment: how are you submitting your form??
i mean you dont have any submit button..

Comment: i don't want to have a submit button, i just want that when the user clicks the checkbox, the view updates. as you can tell, i'm pretty new to rails, so i probably missed something that's big and obvious.

Comment: so then you will have to bind an event on checkbox
and made an ajax call with the value

Comment: ok. how do I do this?

Comment: You can make submit form on checkbox click. Here is solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/2417771

Answer (score 0):

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="map-side-bar">
    <div class="search-filter">
      <form id="my_form">
        <span>Accolades</span>
        <div class="accolades-panel">

          <label>
            Zagat<dd>rated</dd><input id="zagat_status" type="checkbox" name="zagat_status" value="Yes">
          </label>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
function sendData() {
    $.post( "<your post url here>",{'zagat_status':$('#zagat_status'.val()})
    .done(function(data) {
       alert('Success!');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#zagat_status').change(function() { 
         sendData(); 
    });
});
```

Import the jQuery lib and the index.js into the index.html.erb

Comment: err, same question - how do i implement this in the code?

Comment: @hikmatyar dude, put an id attribute to the form and to the input on Javascript. And the put an listener on the checkbox like: $('#checkbox').change (function () { callAjax ();}); something like that... Is not hard... On the callAjax function you can find easy on the Web...

Comment: thanks, but this is still too little detail for me to constitute an answer...(the actual code snipped would help)

Comment: Basically, I am listening to changes on the input and when it changes, it does a POST data using Ajax. You can change the done function to handle the json and show the received data.

Comment: apologies, just saw the code snippet above. let me test.

Comment: still not working. i dumped the code in the answer above into a new index.js file and put that file in the javascript folder.  also: the url i am posting to is '/posts'. nothing happens when i use the checkbox.